# Koa use koa-body upload file problems

Tags: python, typescript, file-upload, koa

My service is implemented using TypeScript and Koa framework.

When the upload API is called by Python, service encounters an error: Error: options.maxFieldsSize (20971520 bytes) exceeded, received 20987791 bytes of field data. This error indicates that the maximum field size limit has been exceeded.

The current package `koa-body` used by Koa will convert the file in the `multipart/form-data` to a field and place it in the body. This has caused the limit of the field size to be exceeded when calling the upload API from Python, while there are no issues when calling it from NodeJs or Postman.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-body

How can I fix it?

`koa-body` has two params to set maximum size, `maxFileSize` and `maxFieldsSize`. The expected reference point was maxFileSize, but it turned out to be maxFieldsSize. Even if I set maxFieldsSize to 3GB, I still encounter the underlying limit of string size 512MB in nodeJS. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35973

python code

```
import requests
file_path = 'test.txt'
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/data'
token = '1234'
headers = {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token),
    }
files = {'firmware': open(file_path, 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print('success')
else:
    print('failed', response.status_code)
print(response)
```

Comment: do you have the typescript code where the router is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's a problem with your HTTP request: you're probably sending the file contents as normal key/value form data  rather than a multipart/form-data upload.

I can't reproduce this otherwise. You should at least share a minimal Koa example and the curl command that reproduces your issue.

For example, here's a minimal Koa server that uses koa-body to parse multipart file uploads:

```js
// npm install koa @koa/router koa-body
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('@koa/router')
const { koaBody } = require('koa-body')

const app = new Koa()

app.use(koaBody({ 
    multipart: true 
}))

const router = new Router()

router.post('/', async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log('headers:', ctx.request.headers)
    console.log('fields:', ctx.request.fields)
    console.log('files:', ctx.request.files)
    ctx.status = 201
})

app.use(router.routes())

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`listening on http://localhost:3000`)
})
```

I can upload files to it with curl:

```bash
curl -X POST -F "foo=@bigfile.mp4" http://localhost:3001
```

bigfile.mp4 is a few gigabytes large, so I get this server error:

`Error: options.maxFileSize (209715200 bytes) exceeded, received 209780570 bytes of file data`